# Selenium Grid Setup using Docker Compose on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

Context :

I am trying to setup a selenium grid to run my UI tests on CI.CI is Jenkins 2.0 and it runs on AWS ECS.When I create a selenium grid using the docker compose and invoke the tests on my MAC (OS Sierra) , it works perfectly.

When run on the AWS ECS , it shows me an :  java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '99.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

The test code itself is in a container and using a bridge network I have added the container to the same network as the grid.

The docker compose looks something like this :

```
version: '3'
services:

chromenode:
  image: selenium/node-chrome:3.4.0
  volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  container_name: chromenode
  hostname: chromenode
  depends_on: 
    - seleniumhub
  ports: 
    - "5900:5900"
  environment:
    - "HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=seleniumhub"
    - "HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444"
  networks:
    - grid_network

seleniumhub:
  image: selenium/hub:3.4.0
  ports: 
   - "4444:4444"
  container_name: seleniumhub
  hostname: seleniumhub
  networks:
    - grid_network
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

 testservice:
 build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: DockerfileTest
 networks:
   - grid_network

 networks:
   grid_network:
     driver: bridge
```

Please let me know if more info is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
unset DISPLAY   This helped me to solve the problem
```

This helps in most cases (e.g. starting application servers or other java based tools) and avoids to modify all that many command lines.

It can also be comfortable to add it to the .bash_profile for a dedicated app-server/tools user.
Can you please try this
- no_proxy=""